# Matching time using re pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match time using re module

matching is required for the following time format

```
02:54 pm
02:54pm
02:5407:46pm
02:5407:46 pm
02:5407:46 p.m.
02:5407:46p.m.
2:5407:46p.m.
2:54pm
02:54
```

I tried using the following pattern

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s?p?\.?m?\.?
```

But these `02:5407:46 p.m.` formats are shown as split format `02:54 and 07:46 p.m.`. I want to consider it as a single pattern and no need to consider separately

**Update**

How to consider `7:00 9:30 p.m.` as a single match group and not split group. I tried with `\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:\s)?(?:\d{2}:\d{2})?\s?[a,p,P]?\.?[m,M]?\.?` which gives a split match group `7:00` and `9:30 p.m.`

Comment: What time is `02:5407:46 pm` supposed to mean? That is just invalid in any "normal" context of `HH:MM:SS`

Comment: @MaxNoe yeah thats true. But i need to match it and split again for future purpose. Its another story :) Only hour and minute willl be present. Seconds not required

Comment: Why not use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats? `14:54/19:46` It's far easier for each producer to work correctly than to make the consumer need to deal with such a mix of non-standard values.

Comment: These time are the data available after cleaning the scraped  url data.

Comment: @imhans33 in that case you might want to look into re-writing the scraping process to retrieve cleaner and well-formed data.

Comment: Just for the record, your pattern will match stuff like `02:54 m`. You might want to change the `\s?p?\.?m?\.?` to `\s?(p\.?m\.?)?`

Comment: Perfect case for playing around in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/qb60id/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:\s)?(?:\d{1,2}:\d{2})?\s?[a,p,P]?\.?[m,M]?\.?` will work

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more elegant ways to write this regex, but this one should to the trick:

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:\d{2}:\d{2})?\s?p?\.?m?\.?
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are cleaning up some dirty data. However, I just cooked up an extended version of your regex, which matches all the lines you mentioned. Its like below.

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2,4}:?\d{0,2}\s?p?\.?m?\.?$
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/wHOrpJ/1)